# Python: How can i avoid specific word in string from lowercasing while using str.lower

Tags: python

Iam new to python

i have a list of string as follws

```
mylist=["$(ProjectDir)Dir1\Dest1","$(OutDir)Dir2\Dest2","$(IntDir)Dir2\Dest2"]
```

i want to lower case each list item value as follows

```
mylist=["$(ProjectDir)dir1\dest1","$(OutDir)dir2\dest2","$(IntDir)dir3\dest3"]
```

ie i want to prevent  `$(ProjectDir)`,`$(OutDir)`,`$(IntDir)` from lowercasing

Answer (score 2):

The idea is very simple. You split the string with a regular expression describing parts that are not to be converted, then convert only its even parts, then join them back.

```
>>> import re
>>> mylist=["$(ProjectDir)Dir1\Dest1","$(OutDir)Dir2\Dest2","$(IntDir)Dir2\Dest2"]
>>> print ["".join([s if i%2 else s.lower()  for (i,s) in enumerate(re.split('(\$\([^)]*\))', x))]) for x in mylist]
['$(ProjectDir)dir1\\dest1', '$(OutDir)dir2\\dest2', '$(IntDir)dir2\\dest2']
```

The main thing here is:

```
[ "".join([
     s if i%2 else s.lower()
     for (i,s) in enumerate(re.split('(\$\([^)]*\))', x))])
   for x in mylist ]
```

You go through the list `mylist`
and for every x produce it modified version:

```
[ ... for x in mylist ]
```

You convert every `x` using this operation:

```
"".join([
     s if i%2 else s.lower()
     for (i,s) in enumerate(re.split('(\$\([^)]*\))', x))]
```

That means: split the string to parts that must be converted (even) and must not be converted (odd).

For example:

```
>>> re.split('(\$\([^)]*\))', x)
['', '$(ProjectDir)', 'Dir1\\Dest1']
```

and than enumerate them and convert all even parts:

```
>>> print list(enumerate(re.split('(\$\([^)]*\))', x)))
[(0, ''), (1, '$(ProjectDir)'), (2, 'Dir1\\Dest1')]
```

If a part is even or odd you check using this `if`:

```
 s if i%2 else s.lower()
```

Comment: @Alp: added the explanation. hope it helps!

Comment: [`import this`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): [...] Readability counts. [...]

Comment: @Matthias: how only can you say this! my code is unreadable? that's a piece of cake!! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are allergic to regular expressions...

```
exclusions = ['$(ProjectDir)', '$(OutDir)', '$(IntDir)']
mylist = ["$(ProjectDir)Dir1\Dest1", "$(OutDir)Dir2\Dest2", "$(IntDir)Dir2\Dest2"]

## Lower case everything
mylist = [s.lower() for s in mylist]

## Revert the exclusions
for patt in exclusions:
    mylist = [s.replace(patt.lower(), patt) for s in mylist]

print mylist
```

Comment: elegant solution. but on large strings or with more complexity this would not be efficient.

Comment: No doubt, though the OP is working with file paths which are unlikely to be large.